# How to sync tasks with Windows Live from Outlook when another account is using Exchange?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

The user has one Exchange account for work as the default, and a couple of IMAP google accounts as secondary mailboxes.

The user would like to be able to have the tasks be stored and sync'd from one of these personal mailboxes. Unfortunately, Google Sync only works with the default account, and that happens to be the Exchange/work account.

Outlook tasks also seem to be stored in Exchange via the work account. The account the user wants to use is set up to link its calendar with Windows Live, but so far no success linking tasks using Windows Live.